# Use the split function or regex expression in python to remove strings between two other symbols

Tags: python

I have the following set of strings in a txt file (archiveONE.txt), where I would like to extract what is between [||||]:

```
[||||]87[||||]2125[||||]1648[||||]2019-04-04 20:17:44[||||]
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
[||||]85[||||]3068[||||]1648[||||]2019-04-04 21:11:44[||||]
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
```

the end result should be this:

```
87 2125 1648 2019-04-04 20:17:44 
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
85 3068 1648 2019-04-04 21:11:44 
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
```

I tried to use the split function in python, but the allowed parameters are few or I didn't get it right:

```
import glob, os, re
from re import sub

fp = open("archiveONE.txt", 'r', -1)
codes= fp.readlines()
for i in codes:
     print(i.split("[",4))
```

I also tried to use Regex expression but something didn't work:

```
codes = re.sub('(?<=\/[*)[\s\S]*?(?=]*\/)', '', codes)
```

Could someone help me find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you simply using `split` function as follows:

```
.split('[||||]')
```

So, for example

```
"[||||]85[||||]3068[||||]1648[||||]2019-04-04 21:11:44[||||]".split("[||||]"))
```

will return you:

```
['', '85', '3068', '1648', '2019-04-04 21:11:44', '']
```

So just remove the first and the last elements from the list and you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

this should work for all but not the last

```
(?<=\]\n*)(.|\n)+?(?=\n*\[)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the pattern with space, then strip the 1st (and maybe the last) spaces:

```
codes= fp.readlines().replace("[||||]"," ").strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the bits to keep cannot contain the characters contained in `[||||]`, I suggest you use `re.findall` with the regular expression

```
r'[^[\]|\r\n]+'
```

[Demo](http://tpcg.io/R9c3AXPr)

The regex reads, "match one or more characters other than left and right brackets, pipes, carriage returns and newlines".